# Can I connect two parts of a sentence with 'regarding' in this case?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I always struggle to write long sentences and connect the parts correctly. Does 'regarding' work here and is there a way to make it sound more like something a native speaker would write?

> I also can't gather the discipline to try to create a plan and work through it regarding how to move on from this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try something like this:  I have trouble mustering up the discipline to create and carry out a plan to help me move on from this situation.

Or, I lack the discipline I need to create a workable plan to get through (or get past) this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, "not necessarily." But all you have to do is relocate that part of your sentence next to "plan" and make it sound more clear.

Like this:

> I also can't gather the discipline to try to create a plan regarding
> how to move on from this situation and work through it.

On a side note, I'd recommend using "a plan as to how..."

Let's say you wanna keep its position. But then, that word wouldn't quite fit there.

Here are some that could work there:

> *in regards to, in terms of*

Even so, the sentence would need a little restructuring. So I'll have stick to my first point.